# How to wrap lines of text that's already written

Tags: emacs

How can I make Emacs automatically wrap lines of text that I've already written such that no line is longer than, say, 70 characters. In other words, I'd like to do "auto-fill-mode" after-the-fact.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Look at `fill-paragraph` and `fill-region`. If I remember correctly, it's bound to <kbd>M-q</kbd> by default. To set the line width, use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `fill-paragraph` and `fill-region`, take a look at these commands:

- `file-individual-paragraphs`: "Fill paragraphs of uniform indentation within the region.
  This command divides the region into "paragraphs",
  treating every change in indentation level or prefix as a paragraph boundary,
  then fills each paragraph using its indentation level as the fill prefix.
  There is one special case where a change in indentation does not start
  a new paragraph.  This is for text of this form:

```
   foo>    This line with extra indentation starts
   foo> a paragraph that continues on more lines.
```

These lines are filled together."

- `fill-nonuniform-paragraphs`: "Fill paragraphs within the region, allowing varying indentation within each.
  This command divides the region into "paragraphs",
  only at paragraph-separator lines, then fills each paragraph
  using as the fill prefix the smallest indentation of any line
  in the paragraph."